# Why is my json rendered as string? How do i parse the string contents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using plupload to perform multipart file uploads. On success, it returns the serverdata that was stored. But i am receiving a string instead of an object containing all my attributes.

This is my controller action:

```
  def upload
      @user = User.create! :name => params[:photo_name], :swf_uploaded_data => params[:photo]
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render :json => @user) }
        end
  end
```

In my Javascript, i have a function that returns the server response, the gist of which is:

```
  function(serverResponse) {
    alert(serverResponse);
  });
```

The output of the serverResponse happens to be a string!! (Ex:

`"{'user': {'name':'photo','link':'http://www.google.com/favicon.ico'}}"`)

Now i just cannot access the link by just doing `serverResponse.user.link` because it is not a serialized output. How do i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the JSON.  See http://www.json.org/js.html for a more secure method than eval.

Notably `var finalObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Comment: I just found out that there exists one in jquery: $.parseJSON. Better for cross browser JSON parsing. Realized that JSON.parse is not supported by Mobile Safari.